# How do I see the properties on a FileInfo (or other .Net) object in the VsCode debugger variable section?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am debugging a Powershell script in VsCode. I set a variable as so:

```
$h = Get-ChildItem models.py
```

$h is a FileInfo object. The properties on a FileInfo object are:

> Directory, DirectoryName, Exists, IsReadOnly, Length and Name.
> [FileInfo
> reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-6.0)

But if I look at the variable "$h" in the Variables section of the debugger, I see the following as its properties:   PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, PSDrive, PSProvider PSIsContainer and Mode.

How do I see the current values of the properties as defined in the reference for FileInfo (Directory, DirectoryName, etc) for $h?

Comment: The `PS*` properties are attached by the FileSystem provider and hidden by default. `Get-Member -InputObject $h -Force` should show them all (you can also access them even though their hidden:`$h.PSPath`)

Comment: Thanks. But that only shows the names of the properties, not their values.